# Pointer from derived class to base class C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I have 100 classes that will inherit 1 base class. Derived class can have `A` and `B` property, just `A` or `B` property, or don't have them at all. I need a pointer, from derived class to base class, that will trigger every time I call `A` or `B` property from derived classes.

```
class D1 : Base
{
    int A { get; set; } // Point to Base A
}

class D2 : Base
{
    int A { get; set; } // Point to Base A
    int B { get; set; } // Point to Base B
}

class Base
{
    int A => ExampleA();
    int B => ExampleB();

    int ExampleA()
    {
        return 10;
    }

    int ExampleB()
    {
        return 15;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    D1 d1 = new D1();
    D2 d2 = new D2();

    d1.A; //return 10
    d2.A; //return 10
    d2.B; //return 15
}
```

Comment: The "managed pointer" here is: `this` - it is the same for the instance, regardless of whether that is talking about `Base`, `D1`, or `D2`; you *might* want to make `A` / `B` on the base-class `virtual` or `abstract`, and `override` them in the derived types? but: what do you expect to happen if someone has a `D2` instance and sets `B` to `25`, then fetches `B`? is it `25`? or is it `15`? or does it matter whether the caller is thinking about `D2` vs `Base`?

Comment: I don't quite understand, `Derived class can have A and B property, or just A or B property`, no they can't they will have both, no matter what, that's how inheritance works. If you want to override the behaivour of a base class, then you'll need to make the base properties `abstract` of `virtual`

Comment: Plus, your base class currently forces all classes that inherit from it to have their properties `A` and `B` be read-only (as there is no setter for them on the base class)

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea in terms of design. https://stackify.com/solid-design-liskov-substitution-principle/#:~:text=The%20Liskov%20Substitution%20Principle%20in,the%20objects%20of%20your%20superclass.

Answer (score 4):

If You want to inherit not everything but sometimes `A`, sometimes `B` and only sometimes `A` *and* `B` then it looks like You should not inherit from the base class at all. Looks more like You should create 2 interfaces and for example:

```
class D1 : IBaseA

class D2 : IBaseA, IBaseB
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to make the properties on the base class `virtual`, so then classes that inherit from it can optionally override the behaivour. (Or you could also make the methods `ExampleA` and `ExampleB` virtual and optionally override that behaivour instead), like so:

```cs
public class Base
{
    // Made these properties get and set, instead of get (read) only
    // default values are for illustration purposes
    public virtual int A { get; set; } = 1;
    public virtual int B { get; set; } = 1;
}

public class Foo : Base
{
    public override int A { get; set; } = 10;
}

public class Bar : Base
{
    public override int B { get; set; } = 10;
}
```

[Let's test it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q6Z7iu):

```cs
var a = new Foo();
var b = new Bar();

Console.WriteLine($"a.A: {a.A}, a.B: {a.B}");
Console.WriteLine($"b.A: {b.A}, b.B: {b.B}");
```

---

If you don't specify anything, `Foo` and `Bar` will implicitly have `A` and `B` with the same visibility as `A` and `B` in the `Base` class. You can't change the visiblity of a member of a class "after the fact" (i.e without changing it in the base class), so if only some of your classes should expose `A` or `B` you'll want to follow what CherryQuery said in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69571289/9363973)

Comment: You are the closest one. I tried virtual and override and its not what I want. Nothing is assigned in `A` and `B` properties in derived class, all of the information is in base class. They are just pointers to methods in base class. And I don't want to assign methods in 100 derived classes just to point to methods in base class, example @Piotr Wojsa . I know that I can do this with reflection and check if `A` and `B` is present in derived class then assign methods to them. I want a simple solution.

Comment: So, you want read and write properties, where the default value is the return value of a method in the base class? If you're solving a problem using reflection, then all simplicity has already gone out the window a long time ago

Comment: Is it possible to write `public int A { get; set; }` in all of my 100 classes and every time I call `Foo().A` it triggers the method in base class `int ExampleA()`, without me writing manually `public int A => base.ExampleA();` in all of my 100 classes?

Answer (score 1):

Actually in Base class you don't need A and B. Subclasses should then look like (assuming ExampleX methods are at least protected):

```
class D1 : Base
{
    public int A => ExampleA(); // note this is get-only property
}
```

Comment: You have 100 classes and you have to write `ExampleA()` from base class every time? Would you do it?

Comment: That's just an example - one might add BaseA : Base with this code and 50 classes should just inherit from it, and another 50 might inherit from BaseB: Base and so on, and so forth.